# start: Job failed to start UWSGI,

Tags: ubuntu, django, uwsgi

Trying to configure ubuntu+nginx+uwsgi+django

upstart script /etc/init/uwsgi.conf

```
description "uWSGI application server in Emperor mode"

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]

setuid voxa
setgid www-data

exec /usr/local/bin/uwsgi --emperor /etc/uwsgi/sites
```

uwsgi configuration

```
[uwsgi]
project = project
base = /home/user

chdir = %(base)/%(project)
home = home/user/Env/project_env
module = %(project).wsgi:application

master = true
processes = 5

socket = %(base)/%(project)/%(project).sock
chmod-socket = 664
vacuum = true

socket = %(base)/%(project)/%(project).sock
chmod-socket = 664
vacuum = true
```

But after running the command **sudo service uwsgi start** I get an error

*start: Job failed to start*

What should I check to handle it?